# google bigtable on terraform cannot take more than two clusters

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform and the resource is google_bigtable_instance. When using more than 2 cluster I get the error:

**Error: Too many cluster blocks
  on  line 0:
  (source code not available)
No more than 2 "cluster" blocks are allowed**

The google web console allows to have up to 4 clusters.

**Could you help me raise the limit to 4?**

Comment: It looks like a fix is underway https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/magic-modules/pull/2121

Comment: That should fix the issue. Thanks a lot.